# Interlocked.Exchange can't be used with generics?

Tags: c#, generics, interlocked

I'm writing a generic class where I need to use Interlocked.

```
T test1, test2;
Interlocked.Exchange<T>(ref test1, test2);
```

This won't compile. So am I forced to use Exchange(Object, Object) instead even tho MSDN advices not to use it that way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work, provided your generic class has the same constraints as `Interlocked.Exchange<T>`, namely, `where T: class`.

From the docs for [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149524(VS.80).aspx):

> This method only supports reference types